# Firebase (android) not returning the reference for an Object

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to retrieve a `Usuario` object from my Firebase Realtime Database.

The command `p.getOferecedor()` returns the highlighted value on the `oferecedor` field of the 2nd image, which matches the UUID of the correct `usuario` I`m trying to retrieve.

I can see from the debugger of Android Studio (see 3rd image) that the reference is indeed set to the correct location, but (see the 1st image) although the reference is set correctly, I'm getting `null` values for all the fields of the object.
Any help is greatly appreciated.
Here's the relevant part of code:

```
        DatabaseReference dbRef;
        dbRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
        dbRef.child("usuario").child(p.getOferecedor());

        dbRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                User user = dataSnapshot.getValue(User.class);
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

Sorry for obsfucsting the fields on the rest of the picture on the 2nd image, but this is an app I'm developing for a company, so the smaller the info I show to you, the lesser the risk of me losing this job.

Edit1 - User.java file and dataSpanshot.getValue().toString value
**value from p.getOferecedor: (directly from LogCat)**

```
onDataChage: returnString: 9t00TAdw2LXCzS8hyrETqTrESVk2
```

**value from dataSpanshot.getValue().toString value: (directly from LogCat)**

```
onDataChage: returnString: {usuario={9t00TAdw2LXCzS8hyrETqTrESVk2={email=pegaiarsa@gmail.com, sobrenome=Palumbo Gaiarsa , crm=0, nome=Pedro, uuid=9t00TAdw2LXCzS8hyrETqTrESVk2}}, plantao={-L6NJKWt9HUR_KG4Qo49={anoFim=2018, minutoFim=30, mesFim=1, inicio=false, remuneracao=3333333, minutoInicio=30, diaInicio=27, diaFim=27, mesInicio=1, local=Kkkkkkk, anoInicio=2018, oferecedor=9t00TAdw2LXCzS8hyrETqTrESVk2, horaFim=14, horaInicio=14}, -L6NHkctPMYGmcOPeyLl={anoFim=2018, minutoFim=24, mesFim=1, inicio=false, remuneracao=3333, minutoInicio=24, diaInicio=27, diaFim=27, mesInicio=1, local=Foda-se , anoInicio=2018, oferecedor=9t00TAdw2LXCzS8hyrETqTrESVk2, horaFim=14, horaInicio=14}, -L6NH_3l4akzIfcJhrv_={anoFim=2018, minutoFim=23, mesFim=1, inicio=false, remuneracao=6666, minutoInicio=23, diaInicio=27, diaFim=27, mesInicio=1, local=Ooop, anoInicio=2018, oferecedor=Jh12qQACjOMyvo3Uo0LEVeitp843, horaFim=14, horaInicio=14}}, historico={9t00TAdw2LXCzS8hyrETqTrESVk2={oferecido={-L6NHkcvnSeJNqLcd5QS={anoFim=2018, minutoFim=24, mesFim=1, inicio=false, uuid=-L6NHkctPMYGmcOPeyLl, remuneracao=3333, minutoInicio=24, diaInicio=27, diaFim=27, mesInicio=1, local=Foda-se , anoInicio=2018, oferecedor=9t00TAdw2LXCzS8hyrETqTrESVk2, horaFim=14, horaInicio=14}, -L6NJKX4n3gjg6ieQmid={anoFim=2018, minutoFim=30, mesFim=1, inicio=false, uuid=-L6NJKWt9HUR_KG4Qo49, remuneracao=3333333, minutoInicio=30, diaInicio=27, diaFim=27, mesInicio=1, local=Kkkkkkk, anoInicio=2018, oferecedor=9t00TAdw2LXCzS8hyrETqTrESVk2, horaFim=14, horaInicio=14}}}}}
```

**User.java**
    package point.cursoandroid.com.medpoint;

```
public class User {

    private String nome;
    private String sobrenome;
    private String email;
    private String telefone;
    private String UUID;
    private int crm;
    private String[] ocupacao;

    public User() {
    }

    public String getUUID() {
        return UUID;
    }

    public void setUUID(String UUID) {
        this.UUID = UUID;
    }

    public int getCrm() {
        return crm;
    }

    public void setCrm(int crm) {
        this.crm = crm;
    }

    public String[] getOcupacao() {
        return ocupacao;
    }

    public void setOcupacao(String[] ocupacao) {
        this.ocupacao = ocupacao;
    }

    public String getNome() {
        return nome;
    }

    public void setNome(String nome) {
        this.nome = nome;
    }

    public String getSobrenome() {
        return sobrenome;
    }

    public void setSobrenome(String sobrenome) {
        this.sobrenome = sobrenome;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getTelefone() {
        return telefone;
    }

    public void setTelefone(String telefone) {
        this.telefone = telefone;
    }
}
```

Comment: There are manly two reason to get a null reference. Either you are not have access to the node due to database Rules or you didn't get the right node path.

Comment: Can you give us the return string of `p.getOferecedor()` and can you past your `User.java` file? If you print `dataSnapshot.getValue().toString()` what you get?

Comment: @shadowsheep there you go

Comment: So one problem is your database reference. You point to your root but you wanna take the user. You must have a second database reference to your child. Then try with a simple User class like the one I suggest you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One problem is that you are referencing your Database root.

What you have to do is take a second database reference that point to your child and use that:

```
DatabaseReference dbRef;
dbRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference childRef = dbRef.child("usuario").child(p.getOferecedor());

childRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    ...
```

Another one is on your `User` class.

If you read the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write) you can see that if you use a POJO to read data from Realtime Database you need to use only this kind of types:

- `String`
- `Long`
- `Double`
- `Boolean`
- `Map<String, Object>`
- `List<Object>`

So you need to convert your `String[]` field to `List<String>`.

Or in order to have a complex field you need to have another java POJO (Plain Old Java Object).

What I suggest to you is to try with the simplest fields and add complex ones one by another once you have tested your POJO with the simplest ones.

So try with that `User.java`:

```
@IgnoreExtraProperties
public class User {

    public String nome;
    public String sobrenome;
    public String email;
    public String uuid;

    public User() {
    }
}
```

That's because if something goes wrong with the POJO creation by reflection you get a `null` reference.

Comment: Thank you so much. I will convert the `String` field to `List<String>`. For now, the change to the child ref was enough. Best regards